# Angular TreeView JSON response

Tags: angular, treeview

I am new to Angular and i need your help !!!

I have a TreeView in my Angular project. i can generate TreeView from my API Response. My problem is I don't know how to send response back to my API with checked/unchecked values so I can save the response where I need it.

```js
    applications_menu_tree: TreeviewItem[];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getApplicationeMenuItems();
      }

    getApplicationeMenuItems() {
        this.appService.getPermissionsListTreeview('Application Menu')
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe(
            response => this.application_menu_list = response
          );
      }
```

Here is the TreeView:

[image]

My problem is: How to take node values from Treeview and send to API as JSON ???

Comment: Check this example - https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/tree-checklist-example.ts

Comment: Hi Jeba. Thank you for your suggestion. I can't open this example, but anyaways, I solved the problem. As it always happens, yesterday I tried for almos 3 Hours and didn't worked. Today I solved in 10 Minutes. Have a nice day.

Comment: try this - https://stackblitz.com/angular/gabkadkvybq
Any way you solved!